# how to improve linq-to-sql query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I am executing the following query in LINQPad:

```
Tickets.GroupJoin(UserRoles, t => t.AuthorId, r => r.UserId, (ticket, roles) => new {
    AuthorId = ticket.AuthorId,
    AuthorRoles = roles.Select(r => r.Role).Distinct(),
    Message = ticket.Message,
    Replies = ticket.TicketReplies.GroupJoin(UserRoles, reply => reply.AuthorId, role => role.UserId, (reply, roles2) => new {
        AuthorId = reply.AuthorId,
        AuthorRoles = roles2.Select(r => r.Role).Distinct(),
        Message = reply.Message
    })
}).Take(1000)
```

Where `AuthorId` is a `string`, `AuthorRoles` a list of `int`s, and `Message` a `string`. This query performs terribly. This query results in an excess of 2000 queries being sent from LINQPad.

- Why is LINQPad unable to translate this into a single SQL query?
- Can I formulate my query differently so that LINQPad is able to perform better?

Comment: What is `ticket.TicketReplies`? How is that LINQ to SQL? You are not assigning a `List<int>` to `AuthorRoles`...

Comment: @NetMage ticket.TicketReplies refers to a collection of replies (incidentally the 'Reply' table). This is LINQ to SQL because it is a LINQ query that gets translated to SQL (in this case by the program LINQPad).  I never wrote that I was assigning a List<int> to AuthorRoles, but a list. Anyways, it is enumerable, and r.Role is an int.

Comment: I was not aware that LINQ to SQL supported collections - perhaps you are using EF6 or EF Core? From your post: "AuthorRoles a list of ints".

Comment: Ah, maybe that is the problem then, that it doesn't support collections. LINQPad doesn't complain though, it just formulates a gargantuan number of queries. By list I meant enumerable, as would be evident from the Distinct() suffix :)

Comment: Can you provide the actual type of `ticket.TicketReplies`?

Comment: Not really, it is something generated by LINQPad that I don't have access to. However, I might deduce the output from GetType() and see if it's IQueryable, but maybe LINQPad will have hickups if I use GetType() inside a lambda inside a query. I'll have to do it at work though, not there at the moment. First thing tomorrow! :)

Comment: If you have full LINQPad, hovering over it should display the type.

Comment: Linqpad generates a LINQ-to-SQL context in the background. And this behavior is just how LINQ-to-SQL works. It's always had trouble with grouping. It first determines the groups and then executes a query per group to actually populate it. Since you have two nested groupings this probably multiplies. You can either restructure the query or create an Entity Framework context (6, because core still has trouble with efficiently executing groupjoin) to do the same query far more efficiently.